# Not able to connect to my local graphql server with apollo studio sandbox

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, serverless-offline, apollo-studio

I am running a graphql server using `serverless offline` and trying to connect to the server with [Aollo Studio](https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer). The weirdest bug is that it was connecting properly a week back and now the exact same server is not connecting. The same thing I have deployed on the AWS and [Aollo Studio](https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer) is able to connect to the deployed server. Any idea what could be the reason for it?

**Environment**

I am on Macbook m1 pro.

Node Version 15.6

As you can in the config file I have started a playground as well on this path `http://localhost:3000/dev/playground` which I am able to access but this playground is also not connecting the server.

One thing which I have observed is my local network IP URL like `http://192.168.1.3:3000/dev/playground` is also not working when I am trying to visit so maybe some kind of network issue might be there.
But when I run something like a React App I am able to access it on this `http://192.168.1.3:3000`

My serverless.yml looks like below

```
service: serverless-graphql-rds

frameworkVersion: "3.8.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: ${env:PROVIDER_STAGE}
  region: ${env:REGION}
  environment:
    JWT_SECRET: ${env:JWT_SECRET}
    DATABASE_URL: ${env:DATABASE_URL}
    REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD: ${env:REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD}
    HUB_SPOT_CLIENT_ID: ${env:HUB_SPOT_CLIENT_ID}
    HUB_SPOT_CLIENT_SECRET: ${env:HUB_SPOT_CLIENT_SECRET}
    HUB_SPOT_REDIRECT_URI: ${env:HUB_SPOT_REDIRECT_URI}

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
package:
  patterns:
    - "migrations/**"
    - "**.js"
    - "config"

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: ${env:httpPort, 3000}
    lambdaPort: ${env:lambdaPort, 3002}
  serverless-plugin-typescript:
    tsConfigFileLocation: "./tsconfig.json"

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: server.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true
  playground:
    handler: server.playgroundHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: playground
          method: get
          cors: true
  oauth-callback:
    handler: ./rest-apis-handlers/oauth-callback.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: oauth-callback
          method: get
          cors: true
```

And the file `server.ts` looks like below which contains the `handler` function

```
import { ApolloError, ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-lambda";
import lambdaPlayground from "graphql-playground-middleware-lambda";
import { verifyToken } from "./common/jwt";
import { useContext } from "./core/context";
import resolvers from "./graphql/resolvers";
import typeDefs from "./graphql/schema";

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ event, context, express }) => {
    const auth = express.req.headers["authorization"] as string;
    if (auth) {
      const [_, token] = auth.split("Bearer ");
      try {
        const user = verifyToken(token);
        if (user) {
          return useContext({
            type: "user",
            properties: {
              ...user,
            },
          });
        } else {
          throw new ApolloError("Not authenticated", "UNAUTHENTICATED");
        }
      } catch (ex) {}
    }
    return useContext({
      type: "public",
    });
  },
});
export const handler = server.createHandler({});

// for local endpointURL is /graphql and for prod it is /stage/graphql
export const playgroundHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  return lambdaPlayground({
    endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  })(event, context, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for 3 days today I finally figured it out.
As I am using the serverless-offline package to run the local graphql server and due to the node version it requires less than 15. [Here](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/1150) is the details discussion on it.

So just downgrade the node version to anything < 15 and it will work.